# How can I return the created data when created success in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my Django project, I have a APIView:

```
class PhysicalServerManualGenerateOrderAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerManualGenerateOrderSerialzier
    permission_classes = [IsFinanceAdmin, IsSuperAdmin]
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
```

in the `PhysicalServerManualGenerateOrderSerialzier`:

```
class PhysicalServerManualGenerateOrderSerialzier(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):

        try:
            order = getOrder(user=user, validated_data=validated_data) # there I create the order instance
        except Exception as e:
            order = None

        return order
```

But I have a requirement, I want to return the created order's id (or other data) when I access the APIView success.

Comment: @MohitSolanki I mean, in the APIView to return the data, so the request user can get the created order.

Comment: `CreateAPIView` return object's details by default. What is your current response? Can you show full serializer's code and  `getOrder` code also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your api as below,

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class PhysicalServerManualGenerateOrderAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    # your code
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)

        sufficent_data = serializer.data  # you will get the serialized data here, which includes the "order_id" too

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

When you call the `self.perform_create(serializer)` the `create()` method of `PhysicalServerManualGenerateOrderSerialzier` class will get called and return the `Order` instance. `serializer.data` will serialize that instance and makes it available at API class